# how does docker-compose map my service names into IP addresses?

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that I use to run a web application.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    entrypoint: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:7000
    ...
  nginx:
    ports:
      # HOST:CONTAINER
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    ...
```

Inside my `nginx` service's container:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.144.4   790c0822b887

$ curl http://web:7000

<h1>Bad Request (400)</h1>

$ traceroute web

traceroute to web (192.168.144.3), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  ec2-user_web_1.ec2-user_default (192.168.144.3)  0.008 ms  0.007 ms  0.006 ms
```

So I can lookup the web hostname and it's mapped to the IP address `192.168.144.3`, but I don't see it in the `/etc/hosts` file.

How `docker-compose` specifically set up this container such that `curl` knows the IP address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docker provides a DNS service](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) (search for “automatic DNS resolution between containers”), and [Docker Compose provides a default “user-defined” network that uses it](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  If you look at `/etc/resolv.conf` inside your container, it should point at a Docker-private IP addresses which provides hostname resolution for both the general Internet and for other containers.

More specifically in a Docker Compose context, the name of each entry in the `services:` block is resolvable as a host name by other containers launched from the same `docker-compose.yml` file.  You do not need to set `container_name:`, `hostname:`, `links:`, or `networks:`; this is all configured automatically for you.

Comment: I saw this before, but forgot to reply + mark as correct. thanks for this! definitely learned something about docker networking from this.

Comment: from a technical standpoint, is there a reason to use `/etc/resolv.conf` rather than `/etc/hosts`? I'm not the most familiar with Linux networking.

Comment: If you use `/etc/hosts` you need to hope you manually entered the same host-to-IP mapping on every system or container, and if you ever add or change or remove an address you have to remember to make the same change everywhere.  With Docker and Kubernetes both providing internal DNS services, cloud providers providing DNS services (_e.g._, Amazon Route 53), and DNS servers like BIND and dnsmasq being prepackaged, you should pretty much never use `/etc/hosts`.